# Problems with javascript to add Class to Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problems with buttons in article example "Home" div 
i main i add a button in div id "Home" see this:

```
<div id="Home" class="tabcontent visible">
<h3>Home</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this)">Go to About</button>
<p>TEXT</p>
```

And i want when user click on that button "Go to About" open page (section) "About"
And problem i see that when user click that button the page was open awesome but the button is not dark gray, i try to add JavaScript when is click that button "Go to About" open page and the section "About" button need to be dark gray but not working for me.
I try this:

```
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this); myscript()">Go to About</button>
```

```
<script>
function myscript(){
elmnt.classList.add('selected');
}
</script>
```

Now when User click to that button "Go to About" the button "About" is not black gray.

See full code:

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt) {
  document.querySelector('.tablink.selected').classList.remove('selected');
  elmnt.classList.add('selected');

  document.querySelector('.tabcontent.visible').classList.remove('visible');
  document.getElementById(pageName).classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
tablink {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 128px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #6D6E70;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.tablink.selected {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6D6E70;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabcontent.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink selected" onclick="openPage('Home', this)">1 Button</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this)">2 Button</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this)">3 Button</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent visible">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>

  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this)">Go to About</button>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>




</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working in the snippet.

Comment: `myscript()` is using an undefined variable `elmnt`. You need to pass something to the function like you do with `openPage()`.

Comment: it would be easier if you refrain from putting javascript code in your html. use addEventListener!

Comment: I try to add `<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this); myscript('About', this)">Go to About</button>` and for function myscript same as in openPage function but seems that not working the script set page to "About" but color of "About" button in top of page not show dark gray @Barmar

Comment: I don't understand why you need `myscript()`. You already add the class in `openPage()`, you don't need to do it twice.

Comment: i add new function myscript() to make the button name "3 Button" to add style dark gray background to that "3 Button" but i see that dont work well @Barmar

Comment: It works when I use Run code snippet above. You must be doing something different on your real site.

Comment: When user click on button "Go to About" the screen looks like this: https://imgur.com/b4bAIsC you can see that in top right of corner button name "3 Button" is background is not dark gray, but i want to when user click the button "Go to About" to top of left corner button name "3 Button" need to be dark gray background see image: https://imgur.com/8rzoUv9 @Barmar

Comment: It works above.

Comment: The button "3 Button" need to be DARK Grey  the button is dark grey when you click it on button, BUT script need to change when FIRST TIME user click on Button "Go to About" and script need to change the "3 Button"  to DARK GREY background color automatically, @Barmar

Comment: I know what you're asking, I just can't reproduce it. I see https://imgur.com/kILRDG3

Comment: When you click button "3 Button" you see that change to DARK GRAY For background but if you try to ONLY click button "Go to About" you can see that that section about is the button "3 Button" NOT DARK GRAY for background you can see that is White Gray i want to be DARK GRAY That show users that is tab selected when they click button before "Go to About" @Barmar

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that other button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the buttons IDs. Then use `document.getElementById()` to provide that button as the second argument to `openPage()`.

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt) {
  document.querySelector('.tablink.selected').classList.remove('selected');
  elmnt.classList.add('selected');

  document.querySelector('.tabcontent.visible').classList.remove('visible');
  document.getElementById(pageName).classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
tablink {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 128px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #6D6E70;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.tablink.selected {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6D6E70;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabcontent.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="homebutton" class="tablink selected" onclick="openPage('Home', this)">1 Button</button>
<button id="newsbutton" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this)">2 Button</button>
<button id="aboutbutton" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this)">3 Button</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent visible">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>

  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', document.getElementById('aboutbutton'))">Go to About</button>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>

</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </p>
  <p>eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, </p>
  <p>vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Work Awesome But I have other question how can i add when user click button "Go to About" when script open that section About i want to browser scroll to top is it possibility? @Barmar

Comment: `elmnt.scrollIntoView()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: I need to add in JavaScript code in middle of function openPage? @Barmar

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. You could also write another function that you call from `onclick`.

Comment: I add on JavaScript and now is working! Thank You :)